# Possible Session Crossing issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a VB.net site that, has been running for a few months.  As the number of users have increased, the occurrences of the issue have increased.  Stored in my session I have the user account logged in.  I run a couple of queries based off of the user logged in and display it in a DataGridView.  A couple of my users have noticed that sometimes when then navigate to this page they occasionally have some data that doesn't belong to them that is showing up, but as soon as they refresh the page it goes away and it is just theirs.

I have tried going in and pulling the session variables and setting them to a temporary variable for the page and then using that to run the query, but I still seem to be occasionally returning 2 users data at the same time.  Like I said though if the user refreshes the page, the other users data goes away.

This only occurs sometimes, but here is the example:

User1 Logs in: Returns

```
          User            Info 
Row 1  User1 Data     ................
Row 2  User1 Data     ................
Row 3  User1 Data     ................
Row 4  User2 Data     ................
Row 5  User2 Data     ................
```

Below is what is supposed to happen and does 98% of the time and after refreshing the page:

```
          User            Info 
Row 1  User1 Data     ................
Row 2  User1 Data     ................
Row 3  User1 Data     ................
```

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the page shows combined rows then it's something in the datalayer, no details available.

Comment: probably you use some static variables that are share to the users.

Comment: I think Aristos is right on the money, more likely a static variable somewhere. The chances of Session being the culprit here are zero.

Comment: But if it is a static variable causing the issue, shouldn't I be able to reproduce this issue by just having two people log in and try loading the page at the exact same time?  Or wouldn't I have this issue all of the time?  I have received the screen shots before showing the issue, but I have never been able to replicate it. Even when attempting logging in as the user.

Comment: Initially I'd thought you might be using some data that might be ambiguous to all users as a means of identifying which information to display to the logged in party, but it seems more likely that the culprit would be some variable that the site uses throughout (an Application variable or something).
As good practice, for logins, you only want to store the user's id field out of the database. Everything else can be queried ad hoc.

Comment: Is your site running in a webfarm?

Comment: Yes. It is a running in a webfarm.  I think load balanced  is across 4 servers.

Comment: If you are using in-process session state, this might be the problem. You can solve this by changing load balance settings, you have to make sure you send the user to the save server he was in. Or alternatively you can store sessions in sql server. Just an option for you to investigate.